# AES encryption with pandas read and write - python 2.7

Tags: python, pandas, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to write a program which takes a data file as an input, converts it into a DataFrame and encrypts a given column using the package Crypto.

The output should consist of two DataFrames/files. The first file should contain the whole DataFrame with the column encrypted. The second file contains the encrypted column with the keys.

My code works fine as it gives me desired output. The problem occurs while decrypting. Somehow, copying the keys from the second file doesn't work using the function `decryption`. The decryption works however outside the program e.g. encrypting the string "python", where the encrypted string and key are outputed to the console works fine.

I think it has something to do with the encoding while reading/writing from/to a file. I've tried specifing the encoding ("utf") but it didn't help.

Any help would be really appreciated. As I am new to coding, any type of constructive criticism regarding programming style etc. is welcome.

### Encryption program

```
# The program takes a file as an input - identifies the format (csv or excel) automatically.
# The output is two files. The dataframe with the column(s) encrypted and another dataframe with the encrypted column(s) plus the keys.


import pandas as pd
import sys, os, base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


### define a class with the attributes file_path und file_format

class InputFile:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path # File path 
        self.file_format = file_path.split('.')[-1]
        # If the file is a csv, ask whether it is seperated with a comma or a semicolon 
        if self.file_format == 'csv':
            self.separator = input('How are the values separated? (, or ;): ')
            if self.separator == 'quit':
                sys.exit('You quit the program')
        if self.file_format == 'xlsx' or self.file_format == 'xls':
            # For Excel, the sheetname should be provided as well
            self.sheet_name = input('Please provide the sheetname: \n')
            if self.sheet_name == 'quit':
                sys.exit('You quit the program')    


    # funktion um die Datei einzulesen, abhängig von dem Format
    def readfile_whole(self):
        if self.file_format == 'csv':
            data = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, sep = self.separator)
        if self.file_format == 'xlsx' or self.file_format == 'xls':
            data = pd.read_excel(self.file_path, sheetname = self.sheet_name)
        return data

    # Funktion um die Spalten zu lesen ,die verschlüsselt werden sollen
    def readfile_cols(self):
        print('Please provide a list of columns you want encrypted. When finished, press Enter without typing')        
        in_data = self.readfile_whole()   
        list_of_cols = []
        while True:
            inp = input().rstrip(' ')
            if inp == 'quit':
                sys.exit('You quit the program')            
            if inp == '':
                break
            if inp in list(in_data):
                list_of_cols.append(inp)

        return in_data[list_of_cols]

def encryption(inputcol):
    block = 16 #bytes encryption
    padding = '{' 
    pad = lambda s: s + (block - len(s) % block) * padding 
    #string gets padded with this Padding depending on its size
    encryptAES = lambda c,s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
    #declare function "encodeAES". A cipher (AES) is used to encrypt the 
    #padded string. Additionally, the encrypted string is encoded in b64 format
    keys = []  #initialize a keys column
    encryptedcol = []  #initialize a encrypted column
    for item in inputcol:
        key = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(16)) #generate a random key of size 16 bytes
        keys.append(key) 
    for key,item in zip(keys,inputcol):
        cipher = AES.new(key)  #creates a cipher out of the generated key
        encrypted_item = encryptAES(cipher, str(item))  #encrypt the 
        encryptedcol.append(encrypted_item)
    return [keys, encryptedcol]


def decryption(key, encoded):
    padding = '{'
    decodeAES = lambda c, e: c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(bytes(e, 'utf'))).rstrip(padding)
    #key = base64.b64decode(key)
    cipher = AES.new(key)
    decoded_item = decodeAES(cipher, encoded)
    return decoded_item


def main():
    choice = input('\n\t Welcome to Encrypto! To quit at any arbitrary point, type \'quit\'.\nDo you want to [e]ncrpt or [d]ecrypt?: ')
    #give the user a choice on how he wants to proceed    
    if choice == 'e':
        path = input('Please provide the folder Path: ') # path of the file to be encrypted
        if path == 'quit':
            sys.exit('You quit the program')
        in_file = inputfile(path)  #file is a class inputfile defined above
        in_data = in_file.readfile_cols()  #read the columns from the given 
                                           #file as a dataframe
        in_data_keys = in_data.copy()  # --''--
        for column in in_data:
            col = in_data[column].tolist()
            in_data[column] = encryption(col)[1]
            in_data_keys[column] = encryption(col)[0]
        # a for-loop which runs through the selected columns, and encrypts them
        #returns a tuple where the first item is the key, the second the encrypted
        #column
        print(in_data, in_data_keys)
        main_data = in_file.readfile_whole()  #read the whole file
        main_data.update(in_data)  #switch the original column with the -
        new_data = main_data  # - encrypted column 
        out_name_data = input('Please provide the name for the output file: ' )
        out_name_keys = input('Please provide the name for the output keys file: ' )
        # names of the output files
        output_path = input('Please provide the path for the output data: ')
        new_data.to_csv(output_path + out_name_data + '.csv', sep=';')
        in_data_keys = pd.concat([in_data_keys,in_data], axis = 1)  #concatenate the keys and encrypted column
        in_data_keys.to_csv(output_path + out_name_keys + '.csv', sep=';')
    if choice == 'd':
        key = input('Please provide the key: ')
        encoded = input('Please provide the encrypted string: ')
        print(decryption(key, encoded))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

The problem could be occuring while reading the files:

```
        def readfile_whole(self):
            if self.file_format == 'csv':
                    data = pd.read_csv(self.file_path, sep = self.separator)
                if self.file_format == 'xlsx' or self.file_format == 'xls':
                    data = pd.read_excel(self.file_path, sheetname = self.sheet_name)
                return data

        # Funktion um die Spalten zu lesen ,die verschlüsselt werden sollen
        def readfile_cols(self):
            print('Please provide a list of columns you want encrypted. When finished, press Enter without typing')        
            in_data = self.readfile_whole()   
            list_of_cols = []
            while True:
                inp = input().rstrip(' ')
                if inp == 'quit':
                    sys.exit('You quit the program')            
                if inp == '':
                    break
                if inp in list(in_data):
                    list_of_cols.append(inp)

            return in_data[list_of_cols]
```

Or while encrypting it:

```
def encryption(inputcol):
    block = 16 #bytes encryption
    padding = '{' 
    pad = lambda s: s + (block - len(s) % block) * padding 
    #string gets padded with this Padding depending on its size
    encryptAES = lambda c,s: base64.b64encode(c.encrypt(pad(s)))
    #declare function "encodeAES". A cipher (AES) is used to encrypt the 
    #padded string. Additionally, the encrypted string is encoded in b64 format
    keys = []  # initialize a keys column
    encryptedcol = []  # initialize a encrypted column
    for item in inputcol:
        key = base64.b64encode(os.urandom(16)) # generate a random key of size 16 bytes
        keys.append(key) 
    for key,item in zip(keys,inputcol):
        cipher = AES.new(key)  #creates a cipher out of the generated key
        encrypted_item = encryptAES(cipher, str(item))  #encrypt the 
        encryptedcol.append(encrypted_item)
    return [keys, encryptedcol]
```

For writing the Dataframes on the csv files, the pandas function `to_csv` is being used.

Comment: Check PEP08 [ https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ ] for a more pythonic naming. Functions should be written in lower_case, classes in PascalCase etc. As your code is a bit unconventional, this makes it harder to read it.

Comment: Could you trim down your problem to the problematic lines? This is quite a lot of code to digest and most of it might not be necessary to help you with your problem.

Comment: I think the problem happens while reading or writing the dataframe. I am using pandas for it. Is there anything I should take into account while encrypting strings on bytes level and using pandas?

Comment: another comment on your code - when operating with paths, better use `os.path.join` and other functions of the `os.path` module as it is safer and works cross-platform. As I do not have a real laptop at hand, now I can not check your code line-by-line. One method to avoid such confusing errors is to use [unit testing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.html). Break down your code function by function and check whether that part works. Maybe you can extract the padding function as well as it looks potentially dangerous to me. Once all parts are tested on their own, then combine.